# how to get last logged in admin time and date after login me in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have 5 Admin in the database. So now I want to get the last user logged in date and time detail. Who worked before me.means after my logged in the dashboard I want to see previous USER login and logout time and date.

I am able to get my (current user) login date and time. But I don't have an idea how can I get previous user(Admin) login and logout date/time detail.

I am sending my login.php code.Where i wrote current user time/date code.Please see the code and give me suggestion how can i get previous user login and logout date/time.
Thanks.

```
<?php include "db.php"; ?>
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$password);
$password = md5($password);
$login_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_username = '$username'" ;
$result_query = mysqli_query($connection,$login_query);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result_query);
if(!$count){
die("QUERY FAILED". mysqli_error($connection));
}
while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result_query)){
$log_user_id = $row['user_id'];
$log_user_username = $row['user_username'];
$log_user_password = $row['user_password'];
$log_user_firstname = $row['user_firstname'];
$log_user_lastname = $row['user_lastname'];
$log_user_role = $row['user_role'];
$log_user_time = $row['time'];
$log_user_ip = $row['ip'];
}
if($username !== $log_user_username && $password !== $log_user_password){
header ("location: ../index.php");
}elseif($username == $log_user_username && $password == $log_user_password){
if($count == 1) {
$_SESSION['username']=$log_user_username;
$_SESSION['firstname']=$log_user_firstname;
$_SESSION['lastname']=$log_user_lastname;
$_SESSION['user_role']=$log_user_role;
$_SESSION['last_login'] = $log_user_time;
$_SESSION['last_login_ip'] = $log_user_ip;

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$current_date = date("F d, Y, h:i:s A"); 
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$query = "UPDATE users SET time= NOW() ,ip='$ip' WHERE user_username='$username'";
mysqli_query($connection,$query);

$last_login_date = $_SESSION['last_login'];
$last_login_date2 = date('F d, Y, h:i:s A');
$diffs = abs(strtotime($last_login_date2) - strtotime($last_login_date));
$year = floor($diffs / (365*60*60*24));
$month = floor(($diffs - $year * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
$day = floor(($diffs - $year * 365*60*60*24 - $month*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));
$hour = floor(($diffs - $year * 365*60*60*24 - $month*30*60*60*24 - $day*60*60*24)/ (60*60)); 
$minute = floor(($diffs - $year * 365*60*60*24 - $month*30*60*60*24 - $day*60*60*24 - $hour*60*60)/ 60); 
$second = floor(($diffs - $year * 365*60*60*24 - $month*30*60*60*24 - $day*60*60*24 - $hour*60*60 - $minute*60));
if($year == 0 AND $month == 0 AND $day == 0 AND $hour == 0 AND $minute == 0 AND $second < 30 ) {
$time1 = 'Just now';
} elseif($year == 0 AND $month == 0 AND $day == 0 AND $hour == 0 AND $minute == 0 ) { 
$time1 = 'few seconds ago';
} elseif($year == 0 AND $month == 0 AND $day == 0 AND $hour == 0 AND $minute == 1) {
$time1 = '1 minute ago';
} elseif($year == 0 AND $month == 0 AND $day == 0 AND $hour == 0 ) {
$time1 = $minute . ' minutes ago';
} elseif($year == 0 AND $month == 0 AND $day == 0 AND $hour == 1 ) { 
$time1 = '1 hour ago';
} elseif($year == 0 AND $month == 0 AND $day == 0 ) {
$time1 = $hour . ' hours ago';
} elseif($year == 0 AND $month == 0 AND $day == 1 ) {
$time1 = 'Yesterday';
} elseif($year == 0 AND $month == 0 ) {
$time1 = $day . ' days ago';
} elseif($year == 0 AND $month == 1 ) {
$time1 = '1 month ago';
} elseif($year == 0) {
$time1 = $month . ' months ago';
} elseif($year == 1 ) {
$time1 = '1 year ago';
} else {
$time1 = $year . ' years ago';
} 
}
if($_SESSION['last_login_ip'] != $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) {
$last_login_ip = "from this IP address (".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].")";
}
else {
$last_login_ip = "IP address ".$_SESSION['last_login_ip'];
} 
}
header ("location: ../admin");
}else{
header ("location: ../index.php");
}
?>
```

So after my logged in on Dashboard (index.php) the page i did echo the variables and i can able to see current user login date/time detail.Which is my login detail.

Please give me suggestion how can i get previous user login and logout detail.
Thanks

notification.php

```
   <span class="pull-right text-muted small"><em></em></span></a>


                               <?php


date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$last_login_date = date("F d, Y, h:i:s A");                               

$last_login_date = $_SESSION['last_login'];
$last_login_date2 = date('F d, Y, h:i:s A');
$diffs = abs(strtotime($last_login_date2) - strtotime($last_login_date));
$year = floor($diffs / (365*60*60*24));
$month = floor(($diffs - $year * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
$day = floor(($diffs - $year * 365*60*60*24 - $month*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));
$hour = floor(($diffs - $year * 365*60*60*24 - $month*30*60*60*24 - $day*60*60*24)/ (60*60)); 
$minute = floor(($diffs - $year * 365*60*60*24 - $month*30*60*60*24 - $day*60*60*24 - $hour*60*60)/ 60); 
$second = floor(($diffs - $year * 365*60*60*24 - $month*30*60*60*24 - $day*60*60*24 - $hour*60*60 - $minute*60));

if($year == 0 AND $month == 0 AND $day == 0 AND $hour == 0 AND $minute == 0 AND $second < 30 ) {
$time1 = 'Just now';
} elseif($year == 0 AND $month == 0 AND $day == 0 AND $hour == 0 AND $minute == 0 ) { 
$time1 = 'few seconds ago';
} elseif($year == 0 AND $month == 0 AND $day == 0 AND $hour == 0 AND $minute == 1) {
$time1 = '1 minute ago';
} elseif($year == 0 AND $month == 0 AND $day == 0 AND $hour == 0 ) {
$time1 = $minute . ' minutes ago';
} elseif($year == 0 AND $month == 0 AND $day == 0 AND $hour == 1 ) { 
$time1 = '1 hour ago';
} elseif($year == 0 AND $month == 0 AND $day == 0 ) {
$time1 = $hour . ' hours ago';
} elseif($year == 0 AND $month == 0 AND $day == 1 ) {
$time1 = 'Yesterday';
} elseif($year == 0 AND $month == 0 ) {
$time1 = $day . ' days ago';
} elseif($year == 0 AND $month == 1 ) {
$time1 = '1 month ago';
} elseif($year == 0) {
$time1 = $month . ' months ago';
} elseif($year == 1 ) {
$time1 = '1 year ago';
} else {
$time1 = $year . ' years ago';

} 

if($_SESSION['last_login_ip'] != $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) {
    $last_login_ip = "From this IP address (".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].")";
    }
    else {
    $last_login_ip = "IP address ".$_SESSION['last_login_ip'];
    }




?>


                                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i> User Name
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small"><em><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></em>
                                    </span>
                                </a>

                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                                    <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Last Login Time
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small"><em><?php echo $time1; ?></em>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                                    <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Last Logout Time
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small"><em>27 minutes ago</em>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                                    <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i> User Ip
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small"><em><?php echo $last_login_ip; ?></em>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
```

here iam getting admin login date and time detail.But i unable to get previous visitor login detail . i can just see only my login time/date detail after login in here.
So please help.

Comment: In stead of using session_start why not look into codeigniter session library http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 3):

I can give you the basic logic for this. In this you can set the session variable that it will act as flag.

```
// start session 
session_start(); 

// if not yet logged in update database 
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged'])) 
{ 
    // update your database here 
   $query = "UPDATE table  
            SET LastLogin=now()  
            WHERE ID='$ID'"; 
   $result = mysql_query($query); // etc... 

   // if the table was updated 
   if($result === true) 
   { 
      // then create a session var 
      $_SESSION['logged'] = 1; 
   } 
}
```

**OR**

You can insert the user id, date and time at the time of login and get it back as last id that will be your previous login.

Comment: No no. this is not I mean. I can update current user login time and date in the database. My question is I have 10 admin in database ok.. so for example I logged in and then after login how can I see last visitor or admin login and logout time.

Comment: See, for example, If you are logged in, then insert the your detail in database like your id, name etc.
By getting the maximum id from the table like max(id), other person can show the login and logout time.

Comment: I still don't understand .Do you mean I can get detail by max date/time  by PHP function MAX(time)  ? Please explain more. I also updated my notification.php file code. where I am getting my login time/date. Please see the full code and suggest me.

Comment: In codeigniter you do not need to use session_start use the session library http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 0):

Create one activity table in database. Click the link to view example here->
[User Activity Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hr64W.png)

Every time when any user logs in, just enter the login time and user id along with other required details in the activity table. At the time of login you can change the login status to deactivated for that particular session. 
Next time when any user logs in you can get the last login time from database and current time from PHP **date()** function. Just get the time difference between those 2 dates and you will get the last login time and duration by previous user.
That's it.

Hope this would work.

Comment: Nilesh Chauhan - ok as per your suggestion i have done. Now i can get login date time and logout date/time. but problem is i can just get my last login and logout detail. So question is how can i get last user login and logout date/time along with his username?
I don't understand method ( Just get the time difference between those 2 dates and you will get the last login time and duration by previous user. )

Comment: @Gurjitsingh - Apply **INNER JOIN** with user master table if you have created in your database and you will get username along with login/logout time.